# How to integrate chromium browser project in Qt Creator in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have managed to understand the structure of **chromium browser** and now I would like to use an IDE in order to make some changes for a personal project on a **Ubuntu Trusty machine ( 14.04 )**.

It is already compiled and I just want to use an IDE to make my life easier.

I have tried to add chromium to **Qt Creator** by using the option `open project` but without any luck.

Could you please guide me to have this achieved ? Some steps would be really helpful. More, it would be possible to compile / build chromium from Qt Creator ? ( avoid typting in console `ninja -C out/Debug chrome chrome_sandbox` and `out/Debug/chrome` every time)

If you guys can suggest me another IDE that you're used to, please, guide me and I will change the title of the post.

---

**//UPDATE 1**

I tried to make those configurations for Build / Run as it follows:

**Build:**
[image: Build step]

**Run**
[image: Run step]

I get the following error:

`:-1: error: No rule to make target`all'.  Stop.`

//**UPDATE 2:**

The error from `Compile output` section
[image: Error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit any code project in Qt creator, but you can't use `Open project`, when it isn't a Qt project. Instead use `Import project -> Import existing project` in the `New project` dialog.

When you have an existing project, you can define new build steps in the `Projects` tab. Under `Build steps` just choose `Add Build step -> Custom Process step`. 
Here you can fill in your command using the fields `Command`, `Arguments` and `Working Directory`. 
In your case, you would for example fill in `ninja`, `-C out/Debug chrome chrome_sandbox` and `%{buildDir}` for the first command.

[image: Add build step]

Similarely, you can click on `Run` (on the top of this tab) to change how the your project is executed after successful compilation.

[image: Add run configuration]

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer. Will check this out after this huge project will load in QT.

Comment: To your edit: this error message comes from the first build step (`make all`). Just remove that build step.

Comment: that worked. Apparently when I press `build` everything is ok but when I press on `run` nothing happens.(a chrome windows should appear). Any hints ?

Comment: First you said the build works fine, but then it doesn't work anymore. Therefore it's difficult to guess what the problem is. Maybe the `ninja` executable isn't found because it isn't on the path? However then it would be strange that it worked in the beginning...

Comment: the flow that I've followed once again is the next one: press `Build Project` which will print in the compile output `Elapsed time: 00:00.` and after this I press on `Run` which prints the following: `Could not start process "ninja" -C out/Debug chrome chrome_sandbox
Error while building/deploying project chromium (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Custom Process Step'
13:34:34: Elapsed time: 00:00.`

Comment: That sounds like the build step is only executed when you click on Run, not when you click on Build. I don't see why that happens, but nonetheless, the problem is probably that Qt Creator doesn't know where the `ninja` executable is located, because it doesn't know where it is located. Try adapting the path variable (using the System environment settings) or use an absolute path

Answer (score 5):

Just run in src folder:

```
gn gen out/Default --ide=qtcreator
```

And open in QtCreator src/out/Default/qtcreator_project/all.creator